# How create a Slide-out Sidebar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want create slide-out sidebar. but I want to do, like in google map or other material design app of google.

If anyone has sample code, please share them with.

**Example**

http://cdn.pttrns.com/pttrns/3304/original/IMG_0015.PNG

Comment: Look out for sidebar..... check JASidePAnels or https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mvysidemenu

Comment: Thank you Debanjan Chakraborty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of libraries that you can use to implement this. I suggest you to visit [Cocoacontrols](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) and find the one that you like the most.

Anyway, try using REFrostedViewController: https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this would be using this awesome controller.

https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController